# DISTINCTCOUNT does not count distinct for total in Power BI with sameperiodlastyear logic

Tags: powerbi, dax

I inherited some DAX code that counts the distinct number of applicants in the same period last year, but it does not count the distinct number in the total, which is important for me. It does count the distinct number of applicants within the various groups, just not in the total.

How it works currently:
Group A has 3 entries: "Peter", "Peter" and "Joe" which equals 2 distinct. Group B has 3 entries: "James", "Susan", "Rick" which equals 3 distinct values. The total is: "Peter", "Peter", "Joe", "James", "Susan", "Rick" which equals 5 total distinct values (this is what I want) but currently it is additive and totals all values.

| Name | Group | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | A | 2 |
| Joe | A | 1 |
| James | B | 1 |
| Susan | B | 1 |
| Rick | B | 1 |
| **Total Group A** |  | **3** |
| **Distinct Group A** |  | **2** |
| **Total Group B** |  | **3** |
| **Distinct Group B** |  | **3** |
| **Grand Total** |  | **6** |
| **Grand Total Distinct (how I want it to count)** |  | **5** |

The measure:

```
Last years applicants = CALCULATE(
   DISTINCTCOUNT(Applicants[applicant_ID],
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Apply time'[Date]),
    DATESBETWEEN(
        Application[applied_date],
        EDATE(MIN(Application[applied_date]), -12),
        EDATE(MAX(Application[applied_date]), -12)
    ),
    ALL(Application[applicationYear)
)
)))
```

Thanks for your help.
I am an amateur in DAX fyi.

I tried a simple DISTINCTCOUNT(Applicants[Applicant_ID]) and it works as intended, ie. is non additive

Comment: Not sure I understand your logic. Why would you expect the distinct count at the total level to be equal to the sum of the distinct counts at the row level? For example, if the data consisted of 6 entries, with Group A having the 4 entries "Peter", "Peter", "Jane", "Emma" and Group B having the 2 entries "Peter", "David", then the distinct counts for Group A and Group B would be 3 and 2 respectively, though the distinct count for the entire set would be 4, i.e. "Peter", "Jane", "Emma", "David". And of course this is not equal to 3+2.

Comment: Agree with Jos. Distinct counts are non-additive.

Comment: I need to adjust my explanation I think because the example you explained there is exactly what I want. Currently it counts distinct within groups but not in the total ie. it is currently additive, I want it to count distinct within groups and in the total (non-additive)

Comment: Better example dataset together with results both current and desired would help.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's going to be difficult to help you further with a posted measure which is completely unrelated to the posted dataset. Suggest you try to debug at your end - for example, if you create a new measure which performs a simple distinct count (without any reference to previous years, etc.), do you obtain the correct total? I'm also slightly confused as to why your current measure references both `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` and `DATESBETWEEN`.